# How can I fetch data from my Power Platform API in a Local React App?

Tags: reactjs

I'm currently working on a project where I've created a web API using Power Platform(power pages , power apps). The API is hosted at "
https://site-8j3on.powerappsportals.com/_api/cra1c_userdetails0d10s?$select=cra1c_firstname0d10,cra1c_fullname0d10,cra1c_lastname0d10,cra1c_emailaddress0d10,cra1c_telephone0d10
". In my local development environment, I'm building a React application, and I'm attempting to retrieve data from this API using the fetch method.

The problem I'm facing is that when I make a GET request to the API endpoint in my React component, I'm not receiving the data along with that I have encountered lot of error messages.

Moreover i have tried with many times , but n outcome please can anyone help

```
api:- 
https://site-8j3on.powerappsportals.com/_api/cra1c_userdetails0d10s?$select=cra1c_firstname0d10,cra1c_fullname0d10,cra1c_lastname0d10,cra1c_emailaddress0d10,cra1c_telephone0d10



import React, { useState } from 'react';
import $ from 'jquery';

function PerformCreate() {
  const [city, setCity] = useState('');
  const [description, setDescription] = useState('');
  const [telephone, setTelephone] = useState('');

  const webapi = {};

  function safeAjax(ajaxOptions) {
    const deferredAjax = $.Deferred();
  
    console.log(deferredAjax)
    shell.getTokenDeferred().done(function (token) {
      if (!ajaxOptions.headers) {
        $.extend(ajaxOptions, {
          headers: {
            "__RequestVerificationToken": token,
          },
        });
      } else {
        ajaxOptions.headers["__RequestVerificationToken"] = token;
      }
  
      $.ajax(ajaxOptions)
        .done(function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
          validateLoginSession(data, textStatus, jqXHR, deferredAjax.resolve);
        })
        .fail(deferredAjax.reject); 
    }).fail(function () {
      deferredAjax.rejectWith(this, arguments); 
    });
  
    return deferredAjax.promise();
  }
  
  webapi.safeAjax = safeAjax;
  

function OnClickUpdate() {
    var accountid = "f137933d-eeed-48a6-b7e7-afa6bea70c4a";
    var jsonObject = {
        "cra1c_firstname0d10": $("#city").val(),
        "cra1c_fullname0d10": $("#description").val()
    }
    UpdateMyEntity("accounts",accountid, jsonObject);
}

function OnClickCreate() {
    var jsonObject = {
        "cra1c_firstname0d10": $("#city").val(),
        "cra1c_fullname0d10": $("#description").val()
    }
    CreateMyEntity("accounts", jsonObject);
}

function UpdateMyEntity(entitynameplural, guid,jsonobject) {
    webapi.safeAjax({
        type:"PATCH",
        url: "https://site-8j3on.powerappsportals.com/_api/cra1c_userdetails0d10s(e93ae55d-be6a-ee11-8df0-6045bd008ec1)",

        contentType: "application/json",
        data: JSON.stringify(jsonobject),
        success: function(result) {
            window.location.reload()
        },
        error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) { 
            alert(XMLHttpRequest.responseJSON.error.message)
        }  
    })
}

function CreateMyEntity(entitynameplural,jsonobject) {
    webapi.safeAjax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "https://site-8j3on.powerappsportals.com/_api/cra1c_userdetails0d10s",
        contentType: "application/json",
        data: JSON.stringify(jsonobject),
        success: function (res, status, xhr) {
            alert("The id created is: " + xhr.getResponseHeader("entityid"));
        }, error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) { 
            alert(XMLHttpRequest.responseJSON.error.message)
        }
    });
}

  const handleCityChange = (e) => {
    setCity(e.target.value);
  };

  const handleDescriptionChange = (e) => {
    setDescription(e.target.value);
  };

  const handleTelephoneChange = (e) => {
    setTelephone(e.target.value);
  };


  return (
    <div>
      <div className="form-group">
        <label htmlFor="city">City</label>
        <input
          type="text"
          className="form-control"
          id="city"
          placeholder="City"
          value={city}
          onChange={handleCityChange}
        />
      </div>
      <div className="form-group">
        <label htmlFor="description">Description</label>
        <input
          type="text"
          className="form-control"
          id="description"
          placeholder="Description"
          value={description}
          onChange={handleDescriptionChange}
        />
      </div>
      <div className="form-group">
        <label htmlFor="telephone">Telephone</label>
        <input
          type="text"
          className="form-control"
          id="telephone"
          placeholder="600000000"
          value={telephone}
          onChange={handleTelephoneChange}
        />
      </div>
      <div>
        <button type="button" className="btn btn-primary" onClick={OnClickUpdate}>
          Perform Web API Update
        </button>
        <button type="button" className="btn btn-primary" onClick={OnClickCreate}>
          Perform Web API Create
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default PerformCreate;
```

` getting the following error messages  ,

"shell is not defined" on Windows"  and "validateLoginSession is not defined"
`